# Matlab - Using conv instead of filter to process a signal

Tags: matlab, filtering, convolution

I'm have the following code to process a signal from an audio

```
[wave,fs]=wavread('my-audio.wav');
t=0:1/fs:(length(wave)-1)/fs;
figure(1);plot(t,wave);
b = [0  1  1.1];
a = [1  0 -0.1];
FIR = filter(b,a,wave);
figure(2);plot(t,FIR);
```

And I'm wondering how, if it's possible, can I do exactly the same with the `conv` function and what would be the difference.

So far, I guessed that I have to turn the audio from stereo to mono. Am I right?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `conv` to perform FIR filtering, but not IIR filtering.  In this case, you have non-trivial denominator coefficients, the filter is IIR and so `filter` is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks! Can I use filter to perform FIR filtering?

Comment: @LukeSpringWalker Yes, just set input `a` of `filter` equal to `1`. Compare `conv([3 6 4 -2 1 -8 -5], [3 -4 2])` and `filter([3 -4 2], 1, [3 6 4 -2 1 -8 -5])`. Apparently `filter` needs extra zeros to "flush" the input: `filter([3 -4 2], 1, [3 6 4 -2 1 -8 -5 0 0])`

Comment: Thanks @LuisMendo ! and one more question. I've been told that there is another function from where I could get the positions vector of the audio, is that function impz?

Comment: Sorry, what is the positions vector of the audio?